# How to execute a test using Xunit and Selenium through a command line where I can indicate the browser and the URL?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, testing, automation, xunit

I am new using Xunit. I have the following Test using Selenium:

```
public class Test:TestBase
{
    private ITestOutputHelper output;
    private IWebDriver driver;
    public Test(ITestOutputHelper output, string browser, string env):base(browser, env)
    {
        this.output = output;
        driver = getDriver();
    }

    [Fact]
    public void Run()
    {
        // Validate the page title
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        Assert.Contains("Selenium", driver.Title);
        output.WriteLine("Website validated");

        // Close browser
        driver.Quit();
    }
}
```

And the following TestBase:

```
public class TestBase
{
    private IWebDriver driver;
    private string browser;
    private string env;
    public IWebDriver getDriver()
    {
        return driver;
    }
    public TestBase(string browser, string env) 
    { 
        this.browser = browser;
        this.env = env;

        switch (browser)
        {
            case "Edge": 
                driver = new EdgeDriver();
                break;
            case "Chrome": 
                driver = new ChromeDriver();
                break;
            case "Firefox": 
                driver = new FirefoxDriver();
                break;
            default: 
                throw new Exception("invalid browser");
        }
        driver.Url = env;
    }
}
```

My target is to execute my Test with a command line like this in CMD:
`dotnet run --project Pipeline -- chrome https://www.selenium.dev/`

But not sure how I can catch the values 'chrome' and 'https://www.selenium.dev/' so they can be used in my test. Such values are examples, I want to be free to introduce any value possible.

I hope you can help me,
Thanks and regards!

P.S. This code is a simple example of what I want to do in my real project.

I tried to use the following code:

```
public class Test : TestBase
{
    public Test(ITestOutputHelper output)
        : base(GetArgumentValue("browser"), GetArgumentValue("user"), GetArgumentValue("environment"))
    {
        this.output = output;
    }

    private static string GetArgumentValue(string argumentName)
    {
        var args = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
        var index = Array.IndexOf(args, $"--{argumentName}");

        if (index >= 0 && index < args.Length - 1)
        {
            return args[index + 1];
        }

        return null;
    }

    // Rest of code
}
```

But I got the following error:
`System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`